# How kubernetes identifies that docker is the container platform that is to be used

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a kubernetes cluster configured. While this configuration is being done we install a container runtime tool for example docker.

But how the kubernetes tool is able to identify that docker is the container runtime that needs to be used while creating containers in the pods ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the below kubelet flags

```
--container-runtime string
The container runtime to use. Possible values: 'docker', 'remote', 'rkt(deprecated)'. (default "docker")

--container-runtime-endpoint string
[Experimental] The endpoint of remote runtime service. Currently unix socket endpoint is supported on Linux, while npipe and tcp endpoints are supported on windows. Examples:'unix:///var/run/dockershim.sock', 'npipe:////./pipe/dockershim' (default "unix:///var/run/dockershim.sock")
```

For more details refer the following link ---> https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`kubelet` instances running on the worker nodes know how to talk to possible container runtimes. It has a `--container-runtime` command line flag that tells which runtime to use.